# 802.1x on Access VLAN only, not on Voice VLAN

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, authentication, ieee-802.1x, mac-auth-bypass

I've successfully configured a Cisco 3750G to perform the authenticator function of the 802.1x process. I have a test Win7 machine as a supplicant and a Windows 2008 server running NPS as the Authentication Server. The Win7 machine is able to successfully authenticate.

I've now hooked up a Cisco 7941 IP Phone in front of the Win7 machine, configured the switch with the **swtichport voice vlan** command, I plug it in and it is granted power, but the port quickly moves to a down state. After looking through the debug logs I believe the issue to be something with 802.1x trying to authentication on both the Access VLAN and the Voice VLAN. Is there a way to only perform 802.1x on the Access VLAN? and not the Voice?

**Scenario:**

```
{RADIUS}  <---->   {3750G} <-----> {Cisco 7941 Phone} <----->  {Win7 802.1x client}
```

I am currently testing on interface gi1/0/3, here is the interface config line:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
  description TestPort
  switchport access vlan 100
  switchport voice vlan 110
  switchport mode access
  authentication port-control auto
  authentication periodic
  authentication timer reauthenticate server
  dot1x pae authenticator
  spanning-tree portfast
  auto qos voip cisco-phone
```

Some of the debugs from the 3750G

```
*Apr 21 13:44:04.045: %ILPOWER-7-DETECT: Interface Gi1/0/3: Power Device detected: IEEE PD
*Apr 21 13:44:04.322: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/3: Power granted
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Interface state changed to UP
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: initial state auth_initialize has enter
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_initialize_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: during state auth_initialize, got event 0(cfg_auto)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811: @@@ dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: auth_initialize -> auth_disconnected
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_disconnected_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: idle during state auth_disconnected
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811: @@@ dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: auth_disconnected -> auth_restart
*Apr 21 13:44:07.811: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_restart_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Sending create new context event to EAP for 0x0000003B (0000.0000.0000)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: initial state auth_bend_initialize has enter
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_bend_initialize_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: initial state auth_bend_initialize has idle
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: during state auth_bend_initialize, got event 16383(idle)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: @@@ dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: auth_bend_initialize -> auth_bend_idle
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_bend_idle_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Created a client entry (0x0000003B)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Dot1x authentication started for 0x0000003B (0000.0000.0000)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev:DOT1X Supplicant not enabled on GigabitEthernet1/0/3
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): Posting !EAP_RESTART on Client 0x0000003B
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: during state auth_restart, got event 6(no_eapRestart)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: @@@ dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: auth_restart -> auth_connecting
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_connecting_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_restart_connecting_action called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): Posting RX_REQ on Client 0x0000003B
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: during state auth_connecting, got event 10(eapReq_no_reAuthMax)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: @@@ dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: auth_connecting -> auth_authenticating
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_authenticating_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_connecting_authenticating_action called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): Posting AUTH_START for 0x0000003B
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: during state auth_bend_idle, got event 4(eapReq_authStart)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: @@@ dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: auth_bend_idle -> auth_bend_request
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_bend_request_enter called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Sending EAPOL packet to group PAE address
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Role determination not required
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-registry:registry:dot1x_ether_macaddr called
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Sending out EAPOL packet
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: EAPOL pak dump Tx
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: EAPOL Version: 0x3  type: 0x0  length: 0x0005
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: EAP code: 0x1  id: 0x1  length: 0x0005 type: 0x1
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/3): EAPOL packet sent to client 0x0000003B (0000.0000.0000)
*Apr 21 13:44:07.820: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0x0000003B:auth_bend_idle_request_action called
*Apr 21 13:44:09.791: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to up
*Apr 21 13:44:10.798: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to up
*Apr 21 13:44:36.844: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Interface state changed to DOWN
*Apr 21 13:44:36.844: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Deleting client 0x0000003B (0000.0000.0000)
*Apr 21 13:44:36.844: dot1x-ev:dot1x_supp_port_down: No DOT1X subblock found on GigabitEthernet1/0/3
*Apr 21 13:44:36.844: dot1x-ev:Delete auth client (0x0000003B) message
*Apr 21 13:44:36.844: dot1x-ev:Auth client ctx destroyed
*Apr 21 13:44:37.842: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to down
*Apr 21 13:44:38.841: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to down
```

---

**Latest Interface Config:**
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 105
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 110
 srr-queue bandwidth share 1 30 35 5
 priority-queue out
 authentication control-direction in
 authentication event fail action next-method
 authentication host-mode multi-auth
 authentication open
 authentication order dot1x mab
 authentication priority mab dot1x
 mab
 mls qos trust device cisco-phone
 mls qos trust cos
 auto qos voip cisco-phone
 dot1x pae authenticator
 spanning-tree portfast
 service-policy input AUTOQOS-SRND4-CISCOPHONE-POLICY

**Global configs**
dad

**Debugs:**

```
show version
Switch Ports Model              SW Version            SW Image
------ ----- -----              ----------            ----------
*    1 28    WS-C3750G-24PS     15.0(2)SE6            C3750-IPSERVICESK9-M

#show authentication sessions interface gi1/0/3
            Interface:  GigabitEthernet1/0/3
          MAC Address:  Unknown
           IP Address:  Unknown
               Status:  Authz Success
               Domain:  DATA
      Security Policy:  Should Secure
      Security Status:  Unsecure
       Oper host mode:  multi-auth
     Oper control dir:  in
        Authorized By:  Authentication Server
          Vlan Policy:  N/A
      Session timeout:  N/A
         Idle timeout:  N/A
    Common Session ID:  0A6363FE0000001900347F3C
      Acct Session ID:  0x00000020
               Handle:  0x7A00001A

Runnable methods list:
       Method   State
       dot1x    Authc Success
       mab      Not run

#show dot1x all details
Sysauthcontrol              Enabled
Dot1x Protocol Version            3

Dot1x Info for GigabitEthernet1/0/3
-----------------------------------
PAE                       = AUTHENTICATOR
QuietPeriod               = 60
ServerTimeout             = 0
SuppTimeout               = 30
ReAuthMax                 = 2
MaxReq                    = 2
TxPeriod                  = 30

Dot1x Authenticator Client List Empty

show run | in dot1x
aaa authentication dot1x default group RADIUS
dot1x system-auth-control
```

**Console**

```
Oct 15 20:16:41.392: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Interface state changed to DOWN
Oct 15 20:16:41.400: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Deleting client 0x74000003 (0000.0000.0000)
Oct 15 20:16:41.400: dot1x-ev:dot1x_supp_port_down: No DOT1X subblock found on GigabitEthernet1/0/3
Oct 15 20:16:41.400: dot1x-ev:Delete auth client (0x74000003) message
Oct 15 20:16:41.400: dot1x-ev:Auth client ctx destroyedshut
Oct 15 20:16:42.180: %SWITCH_QOS_TB-5-TRUST_DEVICE_LOST: cisco-phone no longer detected on port Gi1/0/3, operational port trust state is now untrusted
Oct 15 20:16:43.363: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to administratively down
Oct 15 20:16:44.370: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state tno shut
SW1(config-if)#
Oct 15 20:16:47.801: %ILPOWER-7-DETECT: Interface Gi1/0/3: Power Device detected: IEEE PD
Oct 15 20:16:48.807: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/3: Power granted
Oct 15 20:16:48.916: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to down
Oct 15 20:16:50.124: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Interface state changed to UP
Oct 15 20:16:50.133:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: initial state auth_initialize has enter
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0xD8000004:auth_initialize_enter called
Oct 15 20:16:50.133:     dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: during state auth_initialize, got event 1(cfg_force_auth)
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: @@@ dot1x_auth Gi1/0/3: auth_initialize -> auth_force_auth
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0xD8000004:auth_force_auth_enter called
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Sending EAPOL packet to group PAE address
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Role determination not required
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-registry:registry:dot1x_ether_macaddr called
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Sending out EAPOL packet
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: EAPOL pak dump Tx
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: EAPOL Version: 0x3  type: 0x0  length: 0x0004
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: EAP code: 0x3  id: 0x1  length: 0x0004
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-packet(Gi1/0/3): dot1x_auth_txCannedStatus: EAPOL packet sent to client 0xD8000004 (0000.0000.0000)
Oct 15 20:16:50.133:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: initial state auth_bend_initialize has enter
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0xD8000004:auth_bend_initialize_enter called
Oct 15 20:16:50.133:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: initial state auth_bend_initialize has idle
Oct 15 20:16:50.133:     dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: during state auth_bend_initialize, got event 16383(idle)
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: @@@ dot1x_auth_bend Gi1/0/3: auth_bend_initialize -> auth_bend_idle
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-sm(Gi1/0/3): 0xD8000004:auth_bend_idle_enter called
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Created a client entry (0xD8000004)
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Dot1x authentication started for 0xD8000004 (0000.0000.0000)
Oct 15 20:16:50.133: dot1x-ev:DOT1X Supplicant not enabled on GigabitEthernet1/0/3
Oct 15 20:16:50.141: dot1x-ev(Gi1/0/3): Sending event (2) to Auth Mgr for 0000.0000.0000
Oct 15 20:16:50.141: dot1x-redundancy: State for client  0000.0000.0000 successfully retrieved
Oct 15 20:16:52.113: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to up
Oct 15 20:16:53.119: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3, changed state to up
Oct 15 20:17:34.542: %SWITCH_QOS_TB-5-TRUST_DEVICE_DETECTED: cisco-phone detected on port Gi1/0/3, port's configured trust state is now operational.
```

Port still ends up in a shutdown state, but supplies power to Phone...

Comment: Add the following additional commands, this should take care of your issue. Make sure you have your phones MAC on your NPS - "authentication event fail action next-method"
- "authentication open"
- "authentication priority dot1x mab"
- "authentication violation restrict"
- "mab"
- "dot1x timeout td-period 5"

Comment: Can you post your "sh ver"?

Comment: And can you post your config? Just want to see your global dot1x and AAA.

Comment: Added the latest debugs and the global configs.

Comment: It appears the Cisco 7941 does indeed support dot1x. Need to configure this: Choose Settings > Security Configuration > 802.1X Authentication > Device Authentication. See also EAP-MD5 for the SS in the same menu.

Comment: I believe I got MAB to work, however any PC attached to the phone shows up as Cable unplugged. I've tried connecting 3 different PCs to the phone. I don't see any notifications on the switch either. Like port up or down. No MACs in CAM table....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to configure MAB (Mac Auth Bypass) authentication for the ip phone in the multi-vlan interface. You also need multi-auth so the switch knows to look for more than one MAC address.

-authentication host-mode multi-auth

-authentication order mab dot1x

Comment: mutli-domain or multi-auth? I read that multi-domain is needed if you use two different access and voice vlans?

Comment: When multi-auth is configured, a single authenticated phone is allowed in the voice domain (VLAN), but an unlimited number of data devices can be authenticated in the data domain (VLAN)

Comment: Issuing a "mab" on the interface is all I have to do? Anyone have any good links on how to set this up on the Windows NPS side? Everything I find is for Cisco ACS.

Answer (score 5):

802.1x is port based. So, in simplest form, the port is either authorized or not; once authorized -- MAC limits aside -- traffic from anything will be allowed. Modern 802.1x systems are much smarter ("more complicated") and can independently police multiple hosts on a single port. This is where `multi-auth` and `multi-domain` come in. (consult Cisco [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg3750/sw8021x.html#wp1271507))

As Jaxxs points out, the only compromise is to allow the phone access without authentication (i.e. by MAC.) Because the 7941 won't do 802.1x itself, but will [pass EAPOL through, and "fake" a logoff when the PC port is disconnected.](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/7961g_7961g-ge_7941g_7941g-ge/7_0/english/administration/guide/6141_701_AG/7961ovr.html#wp1048798)

(Ignoring that it's in terms of NX-OS, [this](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/identity-based-networking-services/config_guide_c17-663759.html) is how MAB works.)

Answer (score 1):

CDP should actually take care of the port authentication for an Cisco IP phone. There is a little-known feature called "CDP bypass" which allows a Cisco switch to detect a specific TLV in the CDP message which allows immediate authentication. Be aware however, that newer version of Cisco IOS no longer include this CDP bypass feature.

Comment: On the surface cdp bypass sounds like a security vulnerability and a good thing to remove

Answer (score 1):

The phone must be able to do CDP.  If the switch sees a phone as a CDP neighbor, it will do CDP bypass and will not attempt to authenticate.

Multi-auth is not necessary for a phone.  That will allow multiple machines in the data vlan, which is disabled by default and will show "Security Violation" in the logs.

Multi-domain will allow a phone to authenticate.

You should configure authentication order dot1x mab to do attempt dot1x first.

Also add authentication port-control auto.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/3750xscg/sw8021x.html